# passing data from tableview to viewContoller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, tableview, alamofire

I have a tableview loads data from php json using Alamofire, it loads perfect on the tableview, now I tried to pass the data to a second viewController to show more details, I faced this error which says Cannot find the data in scope

```
func getUsers() {
    AF.request(SiteUrl).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            print("Validation Successful)")

            if let json = response.data {
                do{
                    let jsonData = try JSON(data: json)
                    self.data = jsonData.arrayValue
                    self.tableView.reloadData() // we are already on the main thread
                    //print("DATA PARSED: \(jsonData)")
                }
                catch {
                    print("JSON Error", error)
                }
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    let item = data[indexPath.row]
    customCell.AdTitle?.text = item["title"].string
    customCell.AdDate?.text = item["time"].string

    let imageUrl = item["document"].string
    let url = NSURL(string:("https://qateef-ads.co/uploads/" + imageUrl!))
    customCell.AdImage.sd_setImage(with: url as URL?, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))

    return customCell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsViewController") as? DetailsViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
    vc?.imageView = UIImage(named: url)
    vc?.AdTitle = item["title"].string
}
```

how can I pass the data from to the second view?

Comment: Does your didSelectRowAt method get the data from the cell that was selected first? Which line does it say "Cannot find the data in scope"?

Comment: Which error exactly? Before compiling? Which line? Where?

Comment: errors are here in these two lines. vc?.imageView = UIImage(named: url)
        vc?.AdTitle = item["title"].string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood what exactly is your problem. But if you need to access that data on the second view controller, the simplest way would be to inject that data into the `DetailsViewController` you're instantiating when the cell is selected.
But first you need to create that property:

```swift
class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {
    var data: JSON?
    
    ...

}
```

Then when instantiating that view controller:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
                
        guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsViewController") as? DetailsViewController else { return }
        vc.data = data[indexPath.row]
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

Now you can use that data on your `DetailsViewController` to pull any information you need from the json response:

```swift
class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {

    ...

    override viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let title = data["title"]
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: it says Cannot assign value of type 'JSON' to type 'ViewController' on this line             vc.data = data[indexPath.row]
 @Jobert

Comment: @Jacob I updated my answer to use `var data: JSON?` on `DetailsViewController`

Comment: I appreciate it, but on the DetailsViewController I got this too Cannot find type 'JSON' in scope on this line     var data: JSON?

Comment: @Jacob Where did you get that `JSON` type from? SwiftyJSON? Maybe you're missing an import for that on `DetailsViewController`? (`import SwiftyJSON`)

Answer (score 0):

You pass your alamofire result to "data" variable. Therefore, you should use "data" while passing the value to another VC. In your case, it could be like;

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsViewController") as? DetailsViewController
        vc?.imageView = UIImage(named: url)
        let item = data[indexPath.row]
        vc?.AdTitle = item["title"].string
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok

**

```
    if let json = response.data {
   let JSON22 = json as! NSDictionary
                            do{
                                let jsonData = try JSON(data: JSON22)
                                self.data = jsonData.arrayValue
                                self.tableView.reloadData() // we are already on the main thread
                                //print("DATA PARSED: \(jsonData)")
                            }
                            catch {
                                print("JSON Error", error)
                            }
```

**

If you want to pass your data from `Controller1` to `Controller2`.

In `Controller1`

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)   {

         let item = data[indexPath.row]

         let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsViewController") as? DetailsViewController
         vc!.dictGetData = item
         self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
    }
```

In `Controller2`

Create a Dictionary variable

```
var dictGetData:NSDictionary!
```

then print dictionary on view did load

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       print(dictGetData as Any)
}
```

Comment: I got this Cannot assign value of type 'JSON' to type 'NSDictionary' on this line                 vc!.dictGetData = item

Comment: I Edited my answer please check.