# Protocol Function not being called

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols

Please assist. What I'm trying to achieve
is that when I tap on a specific collectionViewCell the ReportDetailsMapController is pushed and my reports[indexPath.item] is sent from  MainController to the ReportDetailsMapController.

PROTOCOL:

```
 protocol MainControllerDelegate: class {
     func sendReport(data: ReportModel)
 }
```

FIRST VC:

```
 class MainController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var delegate: MainControllerDelegate?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
     
      
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       let report = reports[indexPath.item]
       //When I print(report.name) here. Everything executes correctly 
     
       self.delegate?.sendReport(data: report)

       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ReportDetailsMapController(), animated: true)
    }
     

 }
```

SecondVC:

```
 class ReportDetailsMapController: UIViewController, MainControllerDelegate  {
     
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
    
       let mc = MainController()
       mc.delegate = self

     }
      
     func sendReport(data: ReportModel) {

       print(data.name)//This does not execute when ReportDetailsMapController is loaded.
       print("Report sent")

     }


 }
```

ReportModel:

```
 class ReportModel: NSObject {   
      var name: String?
      var surname: String?
      var cellNumber: String?
 }
```

Comment: A very common mistake: `MainController()` is a brand new instance, it's not the instance in the storyboard (I wish the compiler threw an error). You need the real reference via segue or instantiation.

Comment: @vadian I've been doing the project without storyboard.

Comment: Ok, but `MainController()` isn't the expected controller in the view hierarchy either. Then you have to get the reference from the navigation controller.

Comment: In your case, I think you don't the delegate. What you could do instead is to inject the model into the `ReportDetailsMapController` when pushing to it.

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That method is not called because you didn't assign the view controller you're pushing to the `delegate` property.
When the cell is selected, you could do in this order: initialize the view controller and assign it to the delegate, then call the delegate method and push that view controller:

```swift
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       let report = reports[indexPath.item]
       //When I print(report.name) here. Everything executes correctly 

       let viewController = ReportDetailsMapController()
       self.delegate = viewController
       self.delegate?.sendReport(data: report)

       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }
```

However, I think a simpler and more elegant way would be to simply create that property on the `ReportDetailsMapController` and inject it before pushing it.
There's a similar question/answer related to that here: [passing data from tableview to viewContoller in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65665182/passing-data-from-tableview-to-viewcontoller-in-swift/65665430#65665430)

Comment: Thanks for showing where I went wrong. I will also try your other suggestion.